# Converting a Boolean relationship to the probability curve

Tags: probability, binning

I have two vectors, X and Y. Y[i] is related to X[i]. X is between 0 and 1 (it is a decimal number). Y is boolean, it is either 0 or 1. I want to calculate the probability of Y=1 for different X values. How can I do it?
I was thinking of splitting X into different intervals, such as 0-0.01, 0.01-0.02, .... 0.99-1, then calculating the probability of Y=1 for each of the intervals separately.
However, I don't know if 0.01 is the correct bin size. As I want to do this for so many datasets, I need an automated way of finding the correct bin size.

I work with python, if you could send the related functions in NumPy, Pandas or any other package for this task, I would appreciate it.

Best,

Comment: Your problem is called binary classification. There are many possible methods, like e.g. logistic regression. But we cannot give you the "right" python function because that depends very much on your data.

Comment: "I want to calculate the probability that Y=1 for different X values" is estimation, not classification (classification would be coming along later and adding a *classification rule*, which was not requested by the OP). I agree with mentioning logistic regression as an example approach, but that too is estimation, not classification (not until you then add a classification rule to logistic regression -- but which is not actually part of logistic regression)

Comment: Thanks for your replies, 
If I am not wrong, when we use logistic regression to fit our data, it can fit the data only if the relationship between "X" and the "Probability of Y=1" is either ascending or descending. If the relationship is multimodal, logistic regression can't be applied.

Comment: On the contrary: you can resort to the same techniques used in ordinary least squares regression to model curvilinear relationships: namely, introducing features that are nonlinear functions of the original ones, such as polynomials, splines, *etc.*